# My edit action is using the create action instead of update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following relationship:

```
store.rb -> has_many :products
product.rb -> belongs_to :store
```

routes.rb

```
resources :stores do
  resources :products
end
```

builds_controller.rb

```
def edit  
  @build = Build.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.find(@build.user_id)
  @hero = Hero.find(@build.hero_id)

  @heros = Hero.order('name ASC')
  @items = Item.order('name ASC')

  unless current_user.id == @user.id
    respond_to do |format| 
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'You are only allowed to edit your own builds' }
    end
  end   
end
```

For some reason, whenever I try go to the edit page for a build and try to edit it, it runs the **create** action instead of **update**.

Anyone know what might be the cause of this?

*Also, I'd like the form on the edit page to be filled out with the current data of the build. How do I achieve this?*

My repo: https://github.com/imjp/DotA-Items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from your form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for([current_user, current_user.builds.build]) do |f| %>
```

It needs to be

```
<%= semantic_form_for([@user, @build]) do |f| %>
```

Now, in your `new` action, you also need to prepare the required variables:

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id]) #assuming you have a path like users/id/builds/new
# or @user = current_user if that's what you want
@build = @user.builds.build
```

ps: you should use the `cancan` gem to manage authorizations, instead of doing stuff like `if @user.id == current_user.id` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's still creating new builds instead of updating thoug :/

Comment: When you go on the edit page of a build, the inputs are populated with the build info?

Comment: It's working now! Thanks man. However, it's still not populating the fields though when I go to the edit action. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's because of the way you handle your items I think. You should use `fields_for :items do |item|` and have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :items` in your build controller. Try to read about nested forms :) Also, you're using formtastic, but not really using its syntax. In your build controller, in the create and update actions, I think you should just set @heros and @items if the save or update fails (in the `else`).

Comment: The reason I don't use formtastic's layout in this form is because it screws it up completely. I'm planning on implementing drag & drop in the near future, so by then I will be using formtastic's layout though ^_-. I'll take a look at nested attributes. Thanks for your help.